# Which quantitative approaches recommended to buy NKE in 1985?

Tags: valuation

This is a historical quantitative finance question. [Here](https://s1.q4cdn.com/806093406/files/doc_financials/1985/Annual_Report_85.pdf) is the NKE annual report from 1985. This company increased in value 500 times from 1985 to 2015. Please advise on quantitative finance approaches which would have recommended to buy NKE in 1985 based on this annual report.